# How can i iterate list after it will be out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops

How can I get element out of range from for example this list:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

What I want to do is get element at 12 index forward from 3, so when my list is over it because it has  only 8 elements, it will go from begging and etc. , so i will go like this:

```
4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
```

the answer will be 7, because different between them will be 12.

I tried to do somethink like this:

```
alpha = string.ascii_uppercase
key = []
i = 0
while i < 500:
   for d in alpha:
   key.append(d)
   i += 26
```

To simply expand my list (in this example alphabet list) with some more elements.

Comment: Explanation is not understandable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the modulo operator (%) to wrap around:

```
# either key is a global list or you need to add it as an argument
def get_item_at(index, your_list):
    return your_list[index % len(your_list)]
```

This will always return a value. Example:

```
key = [1, 2 ,3]
for i in range(4, 6):
    print(get_item_at(i, key))
    # or use this line here. It is the same as get_item_at
    print(key[i % len(key)])
# Output
# 1 2
```

Comment: You're missing the `key` parameter.

Comment: Not to jump aboard the "`globals` are evil" train and sound too critical, but you should keep the variables used within the scope of the function. 

Consider wanting to use this function on more than just this specific `list` or even from a module. A good function should be modular with its own scope and not have to rely on others.

That aside, it is a good solution.

Comment: @Axe319 You're right. globals should be avoided. Anyway I wanted to stick to the OP's code, so I used his listname.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `deque`. A `deque` is a collection that you can rotate.

```
from collections import deque

my_deque = deque([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
# rotate it backwards 3 indexes so that 4 is in position [0] 
my_deque.rotate(-3)

for i in range(12):
    # print index [0] and rotate as you iterate.
    print(my_deque[0])
    my_deque.rotate(-1)
```